# How to reverse binary numbers and print them when an input are binary numbers?

Tags: c

My program is the following. You give two positive  decimal integer numbers to it and the program returns all the numbers that are in the interval between those two inputted numbers (included) in a reversed binary numbers.

For example:

```
2 4 //input

01 //reversed 10
11 //reversed 11
001 //reversed 100
```

I have created a short program so far but I cannot successfully implement a function that returns reversed binary numbers.
My program so far looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

//function for converting to binary:
int toBinary (int decimalNo)
{
    if(decimalNo < 2)
    {
        return decimalNo;
    }
    return toBinary ( decimalNo / 2 ) * 10 + decimalNo % 2;
}

//function for reversing number:
int reverseBinary(int binary_particular_number)
{
//not knowing how to do that    
}


    int HI;
    int LO;
    char X[200]={0};
    char test_if_l_c[] = {'c','l'};

int main ()
{
    printf("Input an interval:\n");
    scanf("%s%d%d", X, &LO, &HI); //pokud do LO nebo HI dame pismeno, tak scanf vrati 0
    if ( X[0] != test_if_l_c[0] && X[0] != test_if_l_c[1] || X[1] != 0 || X[2] != 0 || X[3] != 0 || X[4] != 0 || HI <= LO || HI == 0 || LO == 0) 
    {
        printf("Wrong input.\n");
        return 0;   
    }

    int count_in_interval = HI - LO + 1;

    for(int u = 0; u < count_in_interval ; u++)
    {
        int particular_number = LO + u;
        int binary_particular_number = toBinary(particular_number);
        int reversed_binary_particular_number = reverseBinary(binary_particular_number);
        printf("%d\n", reversed_binary_particular_number);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please could you help me to write a function "reverseBinary"that would work for me? I am a beginner in programming.

Comment: Shouldn't `11` be in the example output?

Comment: The `reverseBinary()` function needs to return a string, not `int`, in order to preserve all the leading zeroes.

Comment: According to an internet binary converter no.

Comment: You want all the numbers in the range 2 to 4. That includes 3, whose binary is 11.

Comment: Ohh yes, sorry, you are right..

Comment: It looks as though you need two functions, one to generate the binary string (series of `'1'` and `'0'` characters), and another to reverse a string. Alternatively, and more simply, it is easy to generate the binary digits in reverse order — often, you use a 'reverse string' function to convert the reverse order output into the correct order output.  You simply take the result modulo 2 of the current value, and add either 0 or 1 to the string, divide by two, and null terminate when the current value reaches zero. It is one of the rare occasions where a `do { … } while (…)` loop is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string.h> //you need that for strlen()
void reverseBinary(char binary[])
    {
        int i = 0,j=strlen(binary)-1;
        char temp;
        while (i<j)
        {
            temp = binary[i];
            binary[i] = binary[j];
            binary[j] = temp;
            i++, j--;
        }
    }
```

If you want to preserve all the leading zeroes you should use strings not int.
Also if you want it to work you should change your toBinary() function to return string not int. If you want help with that coment